# Is it possible to integrate a Wordpress blog with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

Is it possible to integrate a Wordpress blog with ASP.NET If yes, then how?

Comment: i also want to integrate wordpress blog with asp.net. if  u got success then please provide me steps for that.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress is written in `PHP`, and asp.net is in  `.Net`. The server side language is different, what do you mean by integrate?

If you are talking about having the main side (`www.mysite.com`) is ASP.NET, and the blog side ( `blog.mysite.com`) is Wordpress, then yes, it is possible. You just have to install the main side and blog side differently, and then use the IIS or Apache to redirect according to the sub-domain name.

If you want the user record to synchronize the data between your ASP.NET and your WordPress blog, then yes, this is possible. But the process is quite elaborate.

When a user registers an account at your ASP.NET, in addition to writing to your ASP.NEt database, you should also write to you WordPress database. I am not aware of any API exposed by WordPress to manipulate its underlying database, so worse come to worse you have to study the WordPress database schema, and maybe the WordPress PHP code, in order to learn how to do the user registration thing.

The same goes for other operation.

In short, you can do whatever you want to do, but it is very tedious.

Comment: Thank you for giving me reply.
My issue is:
In my website (which is developed in asp.net) when user register in my website at that time one blog (which is created in word press automatically) is created for that user.
After when ever user change anything in that blog he log in in my website and all the changes are affected in that blog. In short i want to manage word press blog from my asp.net application.
Is this possible?
I will really appreciate your help.
Thank You.

Comment: Ngu Soon Hui Thank You for giving reply.But I am using MS SQL Server 2005 database in asp.net and in wordpress My SQL database is used.So it's complicated. Is there any another way? 
Thank You.

Comment: @Vatsal, not that I am aware of, my solution seems to be the only way

Comment: @Graviton Where do I set up the redirection in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer and we are using a similar system.  We use linked servers in our Microsft SQL Server Management Studio.  By setting up our linked server we are able to use our variables in MS SQL to affect our wordpress database and are able to control all aspects of our wordpress blog through MS SQL.

Here is a great article about setting up a linked server:

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

If you have any questions please comment: